# CSS or Javascript "help scrolling" horizontally, keeping its items at full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

Is there a way to make animated scrolling "automatic" ?, keeping one element full width each scroll. I wound like to have the **case B** . With "automatic" I mean like it helps you with scrolling preventing the **case A**(unless you are still pressing the screen,but as you release your finger or mouse it automatically scroll It for you based on the percentage of near divs showing)

[image]

Right now my all-divs wrapper looks like so :

```
    .scrolling-wrapper {
         overflow-x: scroll;
         overflow-y: hidden;
         white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

with each div like :

```
.card {
    display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
    width: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: fill-available;
  }
```

Comment: There is a CSS standard for this kind of behavior called [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap), but [browser support is spotty](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints), but good if you only support Chrome and Safari...

Comment: Yup Thanks @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the CSS scroll snap is for; unfortunately, it's not completely supported everywhere. Chrome and Opera are the only browsers that support scroll-snap-stop; all browsers except IE and Edge support scroll-snap-align; and every browser supports some form of scroll-snap-type.

You can use this to your advantage. Note that IE/Edge support a slightly different version of this property than other browsers (I know, we're all shocked) so if you want to support them, you'll have to use vendor prefixes. So put this style on the wrapper:

```
.scrolling-wrapper {
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
}
```